# Is it possible to collect Nectar points via Trainline?

Tags: uk, trains, loyalty-programs, trainline

Since I am not eligible for any Railcard, the only available discount/bonus scheme is [Nectar Card](https://www.nectar.com/) for me. GWR, SWR, LNER and Virgin Trains allow to collect Nectar points and I have already linked a card to my GWR account.

A friend suggested me to use [Trainline App](https://www.thetrainline.com/information/apps), because it can search for bus tickets either. I had a look at the application, but could not see any option for Nectar.

Is there a way to collect Nectar points when I buy tickets via Trainline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Trainline App is a useful tool for planning train and bus journeys and allow you to book tickets. However I cannot find a way to link a Nectar Card to thier App, not every company in the UK is part of the Nectar loyalty scheme but I cannot confirm if Trainline is or not.

The other thing to consider is that Trainline is a third party seller of tickets and charge a small booking fee on their transactions, if you book directly through the various Train Operating companies you will pay a smaller amount and can claim Nectar points at the same time. I would go directly with the companies as much as possible and only use Trainline when no alternative was available.

For Train companies other than the ones listed I would use the [National Rail Enquiries](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk)  website that is the official planner for the UK.

Comment: I have not been able to find recent information. In the past you would get nectar points if you bought tickets on Trainline and got there through the Nectar site. But also then, the cost for using Trainline was bigger than the earning in points.